Rundeck Community alternative sugestion
I’m using the Rundeck community version on a VM to mainly run remote scheduled commands. There are many and on several different remote servers and some of them run every minute.
The problem I’ve been finding is that Rundeck has been consuming a lot of memory and has had frequent crashes even in Jobs that I set up with timeout.
I’m considering switching from Rundeck to another tool (mostly Linux RHEL and Debian environment). Suggestions?
